# Heroku pipelines diff

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-api

I have a problem with the Heroku toolbelt, the pipelines are suddenly not working and prompt the following message :

```
Fetching apps from pipeline... done
Fetching release info for all apps... done

⬢ xxx-staging was not compared to ⬢ xxx-prod because we were unable to perform a diff
are you sure you have pushed your latest commits to GitHub?
```

Is anyone experiencing the same problem, or know how to correct this issue ?

Comment: Here is the command of the preivous output `heroku pipelines:diff --app xxx-staging`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku just published a fix :

`heroku plugins:install heroku-pipelines@2.1.1`